# Standard Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian

What would P (X=Y) be in a joint standard gaussian distribution?

I was thinking to integrate however I am not sure what values to use.

Comment: Isn't it $0$, since $D:=\{(x,x):\, x\in\Bbb R\}\subset\Bbb R^2$ has measure zero and every double integral over $D$ is zero?